# Is it worth caching a single record?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a large Users table that contains over 50 columns that is in use on every page of my application. E.g.

- UserId
- Firstname
- Lastname
- Email
- CreatedDate
- ModifiedDate
- Settings (JSON field, this can contain 4000+ characters)
- And so on..

My idea is that when the user first logs in, I will cache this whole Model into the memory and use that across the website for that user. On every page load, I will check the database record to see if the ModifiedDate has changed for that row since the last time I cached, and if so, do another call for all columns and cache them again.

So essentially, I will still have to do a call to the database on every page to check if the ModifiedDate has changed, and do a second call if it has. The likelihood of the record being changed is very small.

Another idea would be to use Dynamic SQL in a SP to retrieve all fields if the ModifiedDate has changed, so it would then be only 1 call per request in either instance.

Would this be better than just getting all columns on every request? Or is there a better way of managing this?

Comment: Side note: If you end up choosing to cache the record a better value to use to check for changes would be of [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) type instead of a `datetime`/`datetime2`. This is also used for concurrency checks.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of this datatype.

Comment: How long does it take to download a single row?

Comment: What is the role of the `ModifiedDate` field? What business requirement is associated with it? Why do you want to check this field every time the page is reloaded? Maybe it's enough to refresh this field every 10 minutes or every 3 hours instead of every time you refresh the page, in order to reduce the load on the system. Does the user **really have to have a fresh date** immediately after changing it?

Comment: Why cache in web server memory and potentially starve your other processes for memory when you get to large numbers of concurrent users? How will you remove idle users/users who don't log out from cache to prevent memory bloat (since I presume logging out will remove the entry from cache)? How about adding a dedicated caching layer like Redis that scales out readily and can handle expiration and refreshing of cached data?

Comment: @krokodilko The ModifiedDate doesn't currently exist. As Igor suggested, I would probably use a new rowversion field instead.

Comment: @alroc, I'm trying to reduce pressure on the SQL server and increase speed. The web servers we have in place have a lot of unused resources which I don't mind using up.

Comment: The time difference between sending 20 bytes (1 field) instead of 1000 bytes (the whole record) over the network will be almost zero. The query  search time and network latency times will remain the same, and these times are significant here. You will not get any time savings by fetching one field instead of the whole record.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have wide columns, you might as well fetch the entire row back instead of doing the check.  The database still needs to access the row or index and the database caching mechanisms should be keeping it in memory.

One thing you can do to prevent against hanging the application is to use a timeout or asynchronous read.  That allows the page to continue loading with the "old" data, even after a change.  The next page load would see the change.